# I need to slider work with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, mousewheel

Please see this URL:
http://whipwap.co.uk/shopsense/slider_example/slider_test.html

and code is :

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#content-slider").slider({
      mousewheel:true,
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });
});

Now I want to slide with mouse wheel.How I can do this.

Looking for your support.

Thanks,

Deepak

Answer (score 1):

In your `$(document).read()` add this code:

```
      $("#content-slider").bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
          var newValue = $(this).slider("value");
          var step = $(this).slider("option", "step");
          if (delta > 0)
              newValue += step;
          else
              newValue -= step;
          $(this).slider("value", newValue);
      });
```

You might want to decrease animation length or clear the queue in `handleSliderChange()`, because sliding becomes jittery when using the mouse wheel.

Comment: Not getting luck :( Please suggest any other working sample for same kind of work.